# How to retrieve all fields from a Solr collection?

Tags: solr, sharding, solrcloud, solr-query-syntax

Just imagine I have a Solr cluster with 10 nodes. I create a collection name "Test" (numShards=10, replicationFactor=1) and add 1000 documents with 2 or 3 different schemas (eg: doc1(id, field1, field2), doc2(id, field3, field4), doc3(id, field1, field5),...) into "Test".

I can retrieve all fields of any shard, such as **shard1** has fields **id, field1, field3, field4, field5**; **shard2** has fields **id, field2, field3, field5**,... **but** I don't know how to retrieve all fields of **"Test"** collection (in this case they should be **id, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5**) without retrieving fields from **shard1 to shard10** and then join the results and remove duplicated. Is there another way/better way to retrieve all fields from a Solr collection?

Thank you.